# Is this the proper use of ajax, with php - mysql - javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am new to this, so far i was just using html form, click the submit button, the page was refreshing and the data was sented to the server (mySQL). But i learned Ajax (AJAX is a developer's dream) they are saying cause you can:

**Read data from a web server - after the page has loaded**

**Update a web page without reloading the page**

**Send data to a web server - in the background**

So i did a simple example. **Let's say that i have set the sqlConnection.php**

```js
let input = document.getElementById("inputField");

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function (){

    if(input.value == ""){
        alert("empty field");

    }else {
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insert.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { comment: input.value },
                success: function (){
                    input.value = "";
                }

            });
        });
    }
});


function selectQuestions(){
    let data = "true";
    $("#comments").load("select.php");
}

setInterval(selectQuestions, 3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax text</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


<div  class="container py-3">

    <input id="inputField" type="text" class="form-control text-left" aria-label="">
    <div class="py-2 my-1">
    <button id="submitBtn" value="addNew" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="container" id="comments">
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`select.php` has this:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<p>{$row['question']}</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No comments";
}
```

**So my Question**: Is this correct in order to see new results that came from the server ? I call the `setInterval` method every 3 seconds as you can see. Is this bad for the server ? For example if i upload this project to a server and 10 users are using it.. am i exhausting the server - consuming more space ?

Comment: `Is this bad for the server`...yes, potentially. It could use a lot of memory, CPU and internet bandwidth. If there are too many users doing that simultaneously it might crash the server. You could just make it call select.php once after the call to insert.php has finished. Depends if you want to be able to see other people's inserts without refreshing the page?

Comment: @ADyson i understand what you are saying, well yes i don't want to refresh it when the user inserts something.. BUT i also don't need real time comunication. What if i replace the 3 seconds with 40 seconds ?

Comment: Here's a thought. rather than have individual users ping the database continually (which is the main problem with your approach), you might consider caching the results of that query into a text file. Only update the text file when the contents of data changes. So your ajax simply retrieves the text file which is alot easier. Plus 3 seconds sounds excessive

Comment: How big is the `data` table? Downloading the entire table every few seconds could be expensive.

Comment: Better to look for a PUSH to Listeners technology for this, so you only push new data to the client when it exists, not calling for it potentially unnecessarily every X Seconds

Comment: @Kinglish that sounds good but i don't know how to do it

Comment: if you want all users to see each other's changes (you didn't actually answer this point when i asked?) something like websockets or server-sent events would be more appropriate in a modern application, than AJAX polling.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Good suggestion. But you also have to push deletions.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, of course, good point. ___So you only PUSH Amendments___ :)

Comment: @ADyson i have tried to do it with node.js and socket.io it worked fine, BUT this is harmfull for the server to right ?

Comment: @Markos - whenever the table data changes (updated, inserted, deleted rows), run your `select * from data` query and write the results to a text file (json encoded). Then your ajax calls select.php which just does a `file_get_contents()` on the textfile.

Comment: @Kinglish This cuts the Database query out of the equasion, which is probably the most optimized of all the steps, it does not improve the bandwidth flooding or server requests/cpu etc

Comment: @Kinglish Better, get the AJAX call to just read the file, therefore no need to find/run a PHP script

Comment: In fact its not really much of an improvement at all, could even be worse as database IO is probably quicker than a file system access :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly so you think even though i don't need a real time communication with the server.. it's better to use socket.io than ajax?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - perhaps, and the push idea is probably the most appropriate. However, the text file could be hosted on s3 and with the right caching mechanism set, would be better than so many users hitting a database select * query every 3 seconds

Comment: I would have to say yes to that, with the proviso that I dont actually know how you wrote the server end of that

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `setInterval` for every 3 seconds is not my requirement, i can do it every 40 seconds

Comment: But lets assume this is a popular site and 100 or maybe 1000 people are hangin out there at a time

Comment: so it would be like 100 * 40 right ?

Comment: Correct a mundo

Comment: For example a competitor could pay a fairly small botnet to totally cripple your site quite easily

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok so from my conversation with you i will hold the fact to learn better (node.js, socket.io) and do it like real time. I also didn't knew about this (botnet).

Comment: FYI PHP can implement websockets too, as do several other languages (although probably other languages which have more async support probably make a better job of it). It can also implement server-sent events. You don't necessarily need nodeJS or socket.io for that, although they are perfectly reasonable choices if you want to base your stack on that instead of PHP.

Comment: @ADyson i actually didn't know that. Can you please recommend a WebSocket for php ?

Comment: i think this is good http://socketo.me/

Comment: Recommendations are technically off-topic here. If you google "php websockets" you'll see ideas. Ratchet is probably the most complete implementation so far. But I wasn't really saying you should necessarily choose PHP for your websocket implementation. If you have a green field implementation (or nearly green field, i.e. you've barely written anything of note yet) then you might want to look into alternatives to PHP for your whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is in `main.js`, you don't need the `$(document).ready()`, since at the bottom of the `<body>`, your code will only run after everything is ready anyway. Not to mention it's in the wrong place.

At first I thought you were using `.load()` wrong, since its a shorthand for the [event handler](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) `.on('load')`. But it turns out in jquery 3.0 they've added an [ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) also called `.load()`. This is dumb and going to cause alot of confusion, but I digress, use [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/) to get things from a server.

Hitting the server with an interval isn't necessarily bad, it's called polling and it's how the internet did full duplex communication for many years. The problem comes when you poll too often or want to update too much data or have too many users all polling at once. How much is too much all depends on the machine your server is running on. Websockets is definitely a better option, but quite a bit more complex to configure.

I took the liberty to re-write some things, since if you're using jquery, might as well use jquery.

```
let $input = $('#inputField');

$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //assuming this is in a <form>, default action is to reload the page

  if ($input.val()) {
    $.post('insert.php', { comment: $input.val() })
      .done(function() {
        $input.val('');
      })
      .fail(function(error) {
        //error handling code
      });
  } else {                
    alert("empty field"); //alerts are annoying and thread blocking,
  }                       //maybe use a different method to communicate with the user.
});

setInterval(function() {
  $.get('select.php')
    .done(function(select) {
      //whatever you want to do with the response from this
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      //error handeling code
    });
}, 3000);
```

On the php side, maybe just clean things up a bit so that it's more readable. You can use the `->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp) instead of a while loop to get an associated array for the result. Then just [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) that to build you html response.

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli("configs and what not");
  $statement = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM data");
  $result = $statement->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

  if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo implode("", array_map(fn($row) => "<p>{$row["question"]}</p>", $result));
  } else {
    echo "No comments";
  }

  $conn->close();
```